# deserialize a response(possibly json) with c#

Tags: c#, json, formatting

I'm using Google API to translate string. Now it returns a string (possibly json) to me like this:

```
[[["سلام دنیا. ","hello world.",null,null,1]
,["سلام مرد","hi man.",null,null,3,null,null,null,[[["33f65775cb9f74efd0c8c2525938673f","GrecoIndoEuropeA_en_elfahykakumksq_2019q2.md"]
]
]
]
]
,null,"en",null,null,null,0.62470853,[]
,[["en"]
,null,[0.62470853]
,["en"]
]
]
```

How can I deserialize it??

I've used quicktype.io but despite its incomplete guides in comments I cant figure out how to use it.

Comment: If you want to know if a string is a json, just copy/paste it into a json validator.

Comment: if it *is* json, it is the world's most passively aggressive hateful json that hates names!

Comment: yes, that's the problem, The NAMES. because it does not have any names, most validators dont validate this response. but it is google's response and i dont know what can be done....